# Google charts not drawing after ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, chartkick

I have a timeline that displays many Google Charts.

All the Google Charts load properly and display when you hit the homepage. However, there is a "Load More" at the bottom of the timeline. The charts that are generated by this Load More are not drawn.

http://CappedIn.com for exact example. See many charts render successfully. And see bottom and "Load More". After "Load More" the charts do not render.

With debugger I see that`drawChart` is not being called. `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);` doesn't seem to get invoked.

This Load More calls the exact same code to draw the charts. Here is the code in the partial that gets executed while building the Timeline. This code below is included with every chart that appears on the page.

```
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(#{get_line_movement_data(line_movement.event,chart_type)});
      var options = {"title":"#{chart_title}","colors":["#0088cc"]};
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("line-movement-#{chart_type}-#{line_movement.id}"));
      debugger;
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

This code gets called by pressing "Load More" and is included on the original page load.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    // when the load more link is clicked
    $('a.load-more').click(function (e) {
        // prevent the default click action
        e.preventDefault();

        // hide load more link
        $('.load-more').hide();

        // show loading gif
        $('.loading-gif').show();

        // get the last id and save it in a variable 'last-id'
        var last_position = $('.record').last().attr('data-position');
        // make an ajax call passing along our last user id
        $.ajax({

            // make a get request to the server
            type: "GET",
            // get the url from the href attribute of our link
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            // send the last id to our rails app
            data: {
                feed_item_position: last_position
            },
            // the response will be a script
            dataType: "script",

            // upon success 
            success: function () {
                // hide the loading gif
                $('.loading-gif').hide();
                // show our load more link
                $('.load-more').show();
            }
        });

    });
  });
```

I do load the Google Charts js in `<head>` of course.

= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick"

Ruby on Rails project not that it matters.

Any ideas on why charts are not being drawn with the Load More call?

Comment: To anyone viewing this... adding true as a parameter here solved the whole thing... not sure why! google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart,true);

Answer (score 1):

I reload the data into a google datatable, pack that datatable into a google chart view, and explicitly redraw the chart using the view.

```
 // when the load more link is clicked
$('a.load-more').click(function (e) {
// prevent the default click action
e.preventDefault();

// hide load more link
$('.load-more').hide();

// show loading gif
$('.loading-gif').show();

// get the last id and save it in a variable 'last-id'
var last_position = $('.record').last().attr('data-position');
// make an ajax call passing along our last user id
$.ajax({

    // make a get request to the server
    type: "GET",
    // get the url from the href attribute of our link
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    // send the last id to our rails app
    data: {
        feed_item_position: last_position
    },
    // the response will be a script
    dataType: "script",

    // upon success 
    success: function ( data ) { 
        // hide the loading gif
        $('.loading-gif').hide();
        // show our load more link
        $('.load-more').show();


        // get a reference to the line chart
        var chart = window.chartGoogleLineChart;

        // build a new google datatable with the data
        var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);


        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dt);
        chart.formatView(chart, view);

        chart.draw(view, true); 
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Will give this a shot later today :)

Comment: There will be MANY charts drawn after the "Load More" button is pressed. Will there be any conflict?

Comment: No.  I have the charts tiled on the page.  Each chart will redraw the data independently.  If you pass animation parameters the chart will animate the data change.

Comment: You have the code in success: - Previously success only showed the loading gif. I do not have all the data to draw the charts in success.  The data to draw the charts is passed into a partial. I have that partial in the first code block above. The partial has the data for each chart. The partial is called many times with data for each chart.

Comment: The steps remain the same where-ever the data is found.  Get the json data.  Use the google.visualization.DataTable to create a google datatable from the json data.  Wrap the google datatable in a view.  Get a reference to the chart on the page and call draw ... pass the chart the view in the draw function.

Comment: Do you think this could be the problem? `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);`  It is not calling the drawChart function. I feel like I am doing what you are saying... but drawChart is not called.

Comment: Yes.  It should be google.charts.setOnLoadCallback( draw_GVLineChart22 );

Comment: or in your case google.charts.setOnLoadCallback( drawChart );

Comment: To anyone viewing this... adding true as a parameter here solved the whole thing... not sure why! `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart,true);`

Comment: You should pass the chart drawing options instead of true.  I usually pass the options into the draw method, but i omitted it because i didn't know it was required.  But if you pass just true, you might override any previous options.

Comment: Its working 100 percent with the code above and simply adding true after drawChart parameter.